# Get Computer description and last logged on user from OU

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How do I get a list of computers in a particular OU along with the Description and Last logged on user in a .csv?

```
$userName = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machine -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue).UserName
$DisComp = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=LN-*)" -SearchBase "OU=Computers - Disabled,DC=XXXXX,DC=com" | Select-Object Name

$results = foreach ($Machine in $DisComp) {

$Description = Get-AdComputer -Identity $Machine -Properties * | Select-Object Description

   $UserName 
   $Machine
   $Description
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path C:\XXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no AD computer property called LastLogonUser or any other property that holds this information.
To get the user that last logged on, you need to query the windows Eventlog on that computer and search for events with ID 4672

As aside, don't use `-Properties *` if all you want on top of the default properties returned is the Description property.

Try:

```
$searchBase = "OU=Computers - Disabled,DC=XXXXX,DC=com"
$Computers  = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=LN-*)" -SearchBase $searchBase -Properties Description

$results = foreach ($machine in $Computers) {
    # to get the username who last logged on, you need to query the Security log
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $machine.Name -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 50 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $lastLogon = if ($events) { 
                    (($events | Where-Object {$_.Properties[1].Value -notmatch 'SYSTEM|NETWORK SERVICE|LOCAL SERVICE'})[0]).Properties[1].Value
                 }
                 else { 
                    "Unknown" 
                 }
    # output an object
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName     = $machine.Name
        Description      = $machine.Description
        LastLoggedOnUser = $lastLogon
        CurrentUser      = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machine.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).UserName
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Somewhere\Computers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. You of course need admin permissions to query the eventlog, so perhaps (if you are not a domain admin) you need to use the `-Credential` parameter on the Get-WinEvent line aswell.

Comment: Note you have to turn on auditing to get the logons in the security log.

Comment: @js2010 Good point. If the OP actually wants the **currently** logged on user, then he/she could change the output object to hold `CurrentlyLoggedOnUser = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machine.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).UserName`. No digging in the event log needed then..

Comment: @theo How do I implement this within the code, not sure where to place it.

Comment: @Khalifa96 Implement in what? This is all the code you need to get a report in csv format you asked for. If you mean how to add the current user (if any), please see my edit.

Comment: @Theo Thats perfect! thank you. although the "Current User" field appears to be blank. could this be because the computers are offline?

Comment: @Khalifa96 yes, offline, switched off or user logged off. If you feel my answer solved you problem, please have a look at the [tour] where you can read how to mark a question 'done'.

Comment: Is it possible to query the username last logged on a machine when its offline?

Comment: @Khalifa96 No, it has to be reachable

Answer (score 1):

**Define the OU and CSV file paths**

```
$ouPath = "OU=Workstations,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$csvPath = "C:\temp\computer-list.csv"
```

**Use the Get-ADComputer cmdlet to get a list of computers in the OU**

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ouPath -Filter * -Properties lastlogondate,description
```

**Loop through each computer and get the description and last logged on user**

```
  foreach ($computer in $computers) {
      $description = $computer.Description
      $lastLoggedOnUser = $computer.LastLogonUser
      $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
      "Computer Name" = $computer.Name
      "Description" = $description
      "Last Logged On User" = $lastLoggedOnUser
      }
```

**Add the computer data to the CSV file**

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bajan, Looks good but the custom object returns with the Computer name populated but the Description and Last user as blank. How can I fix this please?

Comment: Oops, I missed the -Properties lastlogon, description - try now!

Comment: lastlogon is just the last logon time in a weird format, LastLogonDate is more readable

Comment: Dittto, and also: the OP doesn't want the date, but the name of the user who last logged on instead. You cannot get this info from Get-ADComputer

Comment: @Theo - ah, you are correct - he indeed wants the user, and won't be able to get that from Get-ADComputer